# What is $transaction == BEGIN_TRANSACTION testing for?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to convert some old code by converting to mysqli.  Unfortunately I can't figure out what part of the code is trying to do, so I don't know how to change it.  It seems to be a standard safety check that everyone who uses the original mysql extension used, but I can't find anyone who explains why.  Here is the original code:

```
function query($query = "", $transaction = FALSE)
{
    //
    // Remove any pre-existing queries
    //
    unset($this->query_result);

    if( $query != "" )
    {
        $this->num_queries++;
        if( $transaction == BEGIN_TRANSACTION && !$this->in_transaction )
        {
            $result = mysql_query("BEGIN", $this->db_connect_id);
            if(!$result)
            {
                return false;
            }
            $this->in_transaction = TRUE;
        }

        $this->query_result = mysql_query($query, $this->db_connect_id);
    }
    else
    {
        if( $transaction == END_TRANSACTION && $this->in_transaction )
        {
            $result = mysql_query("COMMIT", $this->db_connect_id);
        }
    }

    if( $this->query_result )
    {
        unset($this->row[$this->query_result]);
        unset($this->rowset[$this->query_result]);

        if( $transaction == END_TRANSACTION && $this->in_transaction )
        {
            $this->in_transaction = FALSE;

            if ( !mysql_query("COMMIT", $this->db_connect_id) )
            {
                mysql_query("ROLLBACK", $this->db_connect_id);
                return false;
            }
        }

        return $this->query_result;
    }
    else
    {
        if( $this->in_transaction )
        {
            mysql_query("ROLLBACK", $this->db_connect_id);
            $this->in_transaction = FALSE;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I can't figure out what they're doing with

```
if( $transaction == BEGIN_TRANSACTION && !$this->in_transaction )
```

Can anybody explain this to me?

Comment: It seems to be checking for the start of a db transaction, which is basically a bundle of operations which are all run at once. This is to stop potential tables changes midway through a set of instructions where external updates could cause mistakes to occur.

Comment: It looks like a constant the original author defined as a flag to pass into the function, to specify whether or not you want to begin or end the transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tokens `BEGIN_TRANSACTION` and `END_TRANSACTION` are arbitrary constants defined eslewhere to make the code more readable. Basically, this entire function is an implementation of MySQL Transactions in `mysql`, which doesn't directly support them. Much of the code is there just to work out whether or not a transaction has been started, and whether to commit it, or roll it back.

You can supprt the same functionality by using `mysqli::begin_transaction()`, `mysqli::commit()`, and `mysqli::rollback()`

The PHP reference is[here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.transactions.php)

Comment: Okay, I think I kinda see what it's doing now.  I'm going to have to get an older version of XAMPP and step through the code because this is way too convoluted to follow in my head.